# django CharField definition

Tags: django, model

In some django models I have often seen

```
myfield = models.CharField(_('myfield'))
class_name = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=128)
```

What exactly is the `_ and tuple` for?   I never saw any such in the official django tutorial snippets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you didn't look at the right spots of the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#standard-translation):

> Specify a translation string by using the function ugettext(). It’s
>   convention to import this as a shorter alias, _, to save typing.

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def my_view(request):
    output = _("Welcome to my site.")
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

Answer (score 5):

Go see at the top of the file, but it's most often this renamed import:

`from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _`

(and so it's a function call, not a tuple)

Answer (score 1):

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _
```

Yes this library is used to translate all strings on your django project, of course you have to mark those translation strings, take a look at this [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/)